# C++ Constructor calling

Tags: c++

Lets assume I have a program:

```
class A {
public:
    A() { cout << '1'; }
    A(int i) { cout << '2'; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Result of this program will be 12.
So my question is - why am I able to call the second constructor through a = 0, when I already created the object and called the first constructor. I don't understand the whole concept of this. Isn't a constructor supposed to be called only once (during object creation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't a constructor supposed to be called only once (during object creation)?

Yes, and that's what happens.

When you do `a = 0;`, the copy assignment operator `A &operator=(const A &)` gets called. Since the second operand is an `int` rather than an `A`, a new temporary instance of `A` is constructed, passed to the assignment operator, and then is destroyed right after it finishes.

Answer (score 2):

The `A(int)` constructor allows implicit conversion from `int` to `A`.

So what happens with:

```
a = 0;
```

is really:

```
a = A(0);
```

If you want to disallow such implicit conversions, you need to make the constructor [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit):

```
explicit A(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of constructor is called "conversion constructor".

These type of constructors are used to perform implicit class-type conversions in C++.

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-35/) you can find a little doc if you want to read.